# QGIS not displaying dates in attribute tabl

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have a QGIS project that links to data in a PostgreSQL database. For some reason, QGIS is not displaying any data in date fields. The date fields appear to be fine in Postgres and I have performed calculations using the date fields in the database. The attribute tables in QGIS show the date field, but show the field as empty. Also, QGIS lists the date field size as -1. I'm using QGIS 2.2 and Postgres 9.0.

I've searched, but haven't seen anyone else with this problem.

Anyone have any insights?